# How to detect browser cookie protection policies?

Tags: firefox, cookies, iframe, safari

Is it possible to determine the user's browser cookie protection policies? Firefox and Safari both disable cross-site cookies for privacy protection:

https://blog.mozilla.org/en/products/firefox/firefox-rolls-out-total-cookie-protection-by-default-to-all-users-worldwide/

https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/safari/sfri40732/mac

This may cause some issues in rendering an iframe such as the Google Calendar Widget:

https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/10249848?hl=en

Is there a way to detect the cookie protection policy in JavaScript to optionally render a different element in place of the iframe?

Answer (score 1):

Since Total Cookie Protection is enabled by default you can expect almost all Firefox users to have it enabled.

Otherwise, from within the 3rd-party iframe you can use the [Storage Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage_Access_API) to find out if you have 1st-party storage access:

```
let hasStorageAccess = await document.hasStorageAccess();
```

This should work in both Firefox and Safari.

You can read more about state partitioning here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Privacy/State_Partitioning

If you're having trouble getting the Google Calendar widget to work in Firefox you can also file a bug here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/

Comment: Thank you for the answer pbz. Unfortunately I do not have access to the iframe, which is bringing in a Google page, so I am unable to leverage the Storage Access API to determine if it will be able to access the necessary cookies. This is very informative nonetheless. I don't think this is a Firefox issue but rather a Google issue in not using the Storage Access API.